# How I can running GUI application on Docker for Mac?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker, docker-for-mac

How I can running GUI application on Docker for Mac?

I want to running wireshark GUI on Ubuntu 16.10

I found docker forum about it, But I can't run GUI app based on content of forum.
Maybe information that in forum is outdated.

How I can run GUI app on Docker for Mac?

Note that I'm using following softwares

Host OS: macOS 10.12.4
Guest OS: Ubuntu 16.10
Docker: 17.03.1-ce-rc1-mac3

Answer (score 1):

Containers themselves don't really have a notion of "GUI" apps; there's no window manager or anything inside the container. It *is* possible though to have a container connect to X11 running on your Mac, but requires some testing and experimenting to get it set up right.

This thread on GitHub may give you more information; https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8710. If you have more questions on that, it may be best to open a new topic on https://forums.docker.com or ask in the Docker Community slack

Answer (score -2):

> How I can run GUI app on Docker for Mac?

you want a full virtual machine running Ubuntu, not a Docker container.

docker is intended to run "server" applications - things without a gui / ui; services that don't require interaction with a user.